# Django Restframe work business logic using serializers or object manager

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

- I need to create a business logic as per the following

  1. Check the student's name is already existed
  2. check the name of the students are having the same registration_number as the one passed.
  3. if the test is true. return validation message "the student having the same registration number already exist"
- models

  ```
  class Student(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      sex = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=255)
      category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

      objects = StudentManager()

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

  class RegistrationNumber(models.Model):
      student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  related_name='registration_number', null=True)
      registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      year_of_registration = models.IntegerField(null=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.registration_number
  ```
- Serializer

  ```
  class AcademicMigrateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      name = serializers.CharField()
      registration_number = serializers.CharField()

      def create(self, validated_data):
          name = validated_data.get('name')
          registration_number = validated_data.get('registration_number')

          try:
              registration = RegistrationNumber.objects.get(
                  registration_number=registration_number)

          except ObjectDoesNotExist:
              registration = RegistrationNumber.objects.create(
                  registration_number=registration_number,
                  student=student
              )
              print("registration number doesnot exist")


          return student
  ```
- views

  ```
   class AcademicMigrateCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = AcademicMigrateSerializer
  ```

Answer (score 2):

first try with new database

```
./odoo-bin -d test1 --db-filter=test1 --dev=all
```

[Visit this link](https://ashusharma.com/odoo-11/install-odoo-11-on-ubuntu-17-10-step-by-step/) to know more about Odoo installation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best if you supplied the terminal errors.
However a possible reasons that  you might get such an error could be that  your server is communicating with the postgres server on the wrong port. By default odoo connects to postgres over 5432.

Answer (score 0):

If the error appears at the time of installation, the more than likely a problem with the postgress, it will be best to uninstall the Odoo and Postgres, delete the resulting files that remain in C:.

Very Important: Enter the register editor Win+R: regedit [HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL] and delete all entries that refer to Postgres

PS: Using regedit on a x64 system these keys will be found under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node, which is the "reflection key" that is mapped to HKLM\Software for 32bits processes running on a 64bits machine. It can be ignored for all purposes except when manually viewing/editing the registry. The installer will run as 32bits so it will find them in the normal location.